# Graph darker cmap colors on top lighter cmap color using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Edit 1: I simplified my question to 4 nodes as the figure [simfilied 4 nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIclZ.png). As the figure shows that the relationship between Pam and Dwight is low (the line connect is a lighter color of red), the relationship between Michael and Dwight is much higher ( darker color of red). How can put the line between Pam and Dwight under the line between Michael and Dwight?

I am graphing the relationship between points in the network. Each point has a relationship with the other points on the network.  Relationships weight range from low (lighter colors) to high(darker colors) using `cmap`. I am pretty sure no one ever asked this question before

My question is: How to stack darker colors on top of lighter colors?

```python
def plot_fig():
    plt.figure(figsize=(40, 40))

    pos = nx.circular_layout(G)

    edges = G.edges()
    M = G.number_of_edges()
    edge_alphas = [(5 + i) / (M + 4) for i in range(M)]

    colors = [G[u][v]['weight']**0.6 for u, v in edges]

    weights = [G[u][v]['weight']**0.4 if G[u][v]['weight'] > 40 else 0 for u, v in edges]
    weights

    cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('Reds')

    nx.draw_networkx(G, pos, width=weights, edge_color=colors,
                     node_color="black", edge_cmap=cmap, with_labels=False)

    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.set_solid_capstyle("butt")
    ax.margins(0.25)
    plt.axis("equal")
    plt.tight_layout()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38MIh.jpg)

Comment: Could you try to make this into a Minimal, Reproducible Example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Could you also elaborate what you mean by *"stack darker colors on top of lighter colors"*?  Do I understand correctly that each pair of nodes has exactly one edge connecting them? So the only overlaps happen where edges cross?

Comment: Could you create a toy data set similar to your real data? For example with just 4 nodes and 6 edges?

Comment: @lydia-van-dyke I made an edit to further clarify the question